# Sum of 4 elements in java array equaling to k, duplicated array elements

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I've a homework of a code which searches for four numbers in an array whose sum equals to k (in this example, k = 10). The same array elements can be used more than once. In other words, it sums four elements of the array, compares the sums to value k, and returns true if they are equal, or moves on to other elements if not. So far the code sums four distinct elements of the array but I would need to alter it so that it works also when any single element is used in the sum of four elements more than once, for example if array[2] * 4 == k or array[0] * 2 + array[1] * 2 == k, it returns true.

"static int[][] esim" in the code are example inputs. For instance, {1, 2, 3, 4} returns true, because 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 == k when k = 10. {4, 3, 1, 5, 5, 6, 6} returns false when true is expected, because the code does not take into account duplicated elements and therefore ignores that 2 * 4 + 2 * 1 == k. Similarly {2, 3} returns false when true is expected, although 2 * 2 + 2 * 3 == k.

Anyone could give me a hint how to achieve what I want?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Etsinta2 {

    public static boolean etsi(int[] tl, int k) {
        Arrays.sort(tl);
        for (int i = 0; i < tl.length; i++) {
            int b = i + 1;
            int c = i + 2;
            int d = tl.length - 1;
            while (b < d) {
                if (tl[i] + tl[b] + tl[c] + tl[d] == k) {
                    return true;
                } else if (tl[i] + tl[b] + tl[c] + tl[d] < k) {
                    b++;
                    c++;
                } else {
                    d--;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    static int[][] esim = new int[][]{{5},
        {2, 3},
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {4, 2, 3, 1},
        {4, 6, 5, 5},
        {6, 4, 5, 5},
        {6, 6, 6, 4},
        {4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6},
        {9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 6},
        {4, 3, 1, 5, 5, 6, 6}};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int[] taulu : esim) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(taulu) + " 10 : " + etsi(taulu, 10));
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify, what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my description to be clearer about this.

Comment: Give example input and (correct) output.

Comment: My description edited again accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking if the total sum of elements is a multiple of k?  If so, you could just sum all elements and check if % (mod) k is zero (i.e. no remainder after dividing by k).

**Edit:** Okay I read the question again and I think the question is to find 4 numbers from the array (and duplicating the numbers are okay) to sum to k.

(Sorry I tried to delete this answer but couldn't easily)

So here's a swing at the solution:  Have four nested loops, one for each "number slot".  Let each loop pick one number at a time from the array (therefore allowing duplicate selections).  Check the sum in the inner-most loop.  If it's k, break w/ `true`.  If not true at the end, `false`.

Comment: Yes, that's the crude but working solution. Unfortunately the four loops make up to O(n⁴), whereas the homework apparently expects a O(n² log n) solution.

Comment: @MariaNiku LOL I was just about to edit it to say that it's super-inefficient...  Does the n^2 log n include the sort, or does it assume a sorted array?

Comment: Yes, it includes the sort - although in the code as I have it that doesn't seem to make a difference for the end result.

Comment: Sorry I'm at a bit of a block.  The only thing I can think of ATM is a "cheat" where you work entirely in k-space, breaking up the result (10) into ALL POSSIBLE array answer combinations.  This is also slow as anything and as large as everything, but it technically is not in n-space, so in the end, when you get an input array you can just do a lookup for the answer, in MUCH less than n^2 log n time...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a different solution which should bring the time complexity to O(n^2 log n). This uses an auxiliary list which stores all possible sums of pairs of array elements and then compares the sums of pairs of these sums to k. Here's the edited method where I've used an ArrayList. It works fine, except that it's still too slow: the homework is submitted via a robo tester, and a hidden test apparently testing with large numbers, clocks 27.0 ms whereas the required max is 25.0 ms. Is there any way I could speed up the code a little with some minor changes?

```
public static boolean etsi(int[] tl, int k) {
    ArrayList<Integer> summat = new ArrayList<Integer>() 
    Arrays.sort(tl);

    for (int i = 0; i < tl.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tl.length; j++) {
            summat.add(tl[i] + tl[j]);
        }
    }
    int a = 0;
    int b = summat.size() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < summat.size(); i++) {
        if (summat.get(a) + summat.get(b) == k) {
            return true;
        } else if (summat.get(a) + summat.get(b) < k) {
            a++;
        } else {
            b--;
        }
    }

    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Ah, actually, ignore that. Found the necessary minor change and was able to pass the homework. Many thanks for your suggestions, SeKa, as well as to the others who instructed me to be more specific.

Comment: Gratz for getting through it on your own!